# How to read URIs from RDFLib using Python?

Tags: python, uri, html-parsing, rdf, ontology

I have several thousands `URIRef` ontology values that I'm trying to get a string representation of:

```
[rdflib.term.URIRef('http://purl.obolibrary.org/obo/RO_0002219'),
 rdflib.term.URIRef('http://purl.obolibrary.org/obo/RO_0002551'),
rdflib.term.URIRef('http://purl.obolibrary.org/obo/uberon/core#indirectly_supplies')]
```

I could go to each one's link individually (eg `http://purl.obolibrary.org/obo/RO_0002219`) and get it (e.g `surrounded by`), but how can I do it with Python? There are 2 ways that I see how to do it but I couldn't figure out either. One way would be simply to use `RDFLib` library, but I didn't find a function that translates the link. Another way would be to parse the `HTML` link to get the red value (I think that's corresponds to the translation).

Note that some of them don't have anything attached to them (eg `http://purl.obolibrary.org/obo/uberon/core#indirectly_supplies` is `404: Not Found`)

Comment: did you try this? https://rdflib.readthedocs.io/en/stable/intro_to_parsing.html#reading-remote-rdf - I mean, the URI can return just RDF data which you can load into a graph

Comment: @UninformedUser I have tried it but couldn't get the translation/actual meaning from `rdflib`. Are you saying there is no way to do it since it just returns the RDF data?

Comment: I meant to get the RDF data by using the URI - that's one of the principles of Linked Data - returns an RDF representation of the entity. As you could see in the answer below, it's pretty much straightforward. You can parse this RDF data into an rdflib Graph object - that's why I forwarded you the link - sorry, I should have been more specific

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since those URIs support RDF content negotiation you can just get the rdf and load it into a graph, shown below. Once you have the graph, you can query the properties that you want out of it with SPARQL. In the example below, I fetch the label of each of your subjects. I also removed one of the URIs that you provided since it 404's.

```
from rdflib import Graph, URIRef

uris = [URIRef('http://purl.obolibrary.org/obo/RO_0002219'), URIRef('http://purl.obolibrary.org/obo/RO_0002551')]

for uri in uris:
   query = """
   SELECT ?label WHERE {
      <"""+str(uri)+"""> rdfs:label ?label.
   }
   """
   g = Graph()
   g.parse(uri)
   res = g.query(query)
   for result in res:
      print(result)
```

This gives an output,

```
(rdflib.term.Literal('surrounded by', lang='en'),)
(rdflib.term.Literal('has skeleton'),)
```